# Rewrites are not working well in A React Project deployed in AWS amplify

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, proxy, reverse-proxy, aws-amplify

I made a react project with `create-react-app` and deployed it via AWS Amplify.

I was trying to **rewrites** several routes under the same domain to open the other web sites. It seems like using the way of **reverse-proxy**.

So, through `Rewrites and redirects` console, I added a rule like below.

| Source address | Target Address | Type |
| --- | --- | --- |
| /test/<*> | (a different origin which is deployed in the amplify, too) | 200 (Rewrite) |

However, when the `/test` has been routed, the `rewrites` is not working. Looking into the `Network` tab in devtools, the browser tried to fetch static files from the **Target address** domain, but it fails.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is caused by SPA redirect configuration
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/redirects.html#redirects-for-single-page-web-apps-spa

`/<*>  index.html  200`
Or similar redirect. Cause this is taking priority over reverse proxy config.

In my case I solved it, putting the reverse proxy config on the top. and SPA config at button.